# Loop through two lists each containing arrays and return count of similar arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have multiple lists each containing arrays and I would like to get the number of arrays that match within 2 list. I have found similar questions but everything I have tried does not matter. I have tried doing it this way, but I always get a count of 0 and I know I should have at least 1 array that match in both list.

```
    for i in l1:
         for j in l2:
                count = 0
                if i == j:
                    count+=1 
                else:
                    pass
```

I have also tried using **set** and **intersection** to count the similar arrays but it did not work. I also changed the items in my list to tuples in order to do this.

I have also tried moving the counter = 0 outside of my for loop, but returns this error:

```
     ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

for the following line of code:

```
    if i==j:
```

*Example:*

l1 = [[1.00,1.65,3.45,0.5][1.80,1.90,3.00,0.5]**[1.02,1.89,3.45,0.5]**]

l2 = [[1.35,2.00,3.60,0.7]**[1.02,1.89,3.45,0.5]**[2.22,1.30,3.00,0.7]]

Output would be: 1

I just want to return the number of arrays that appear in both lists.

Any suggestions for me...

Comment: Can you provide example input and expected output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: *multiple* as in *more than two*?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis  Yes, I am technically comparing 4 lists but two at a time

Comment: @L.Rodriguez You have declared count=0 inside the for loop which is resetting its value to 0 at each iteration. Declare it outside the loops to get the correct answer using your above code

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work if you modify it as such:

```
l1 = [[1.00,1.65,3.45,0.5],[1.80,1.90,3.00,0.5],[1.02,1.89,3.45,0.5]]
l2 = [[1.35,2.00,3.60,0.7],[1.02,1.89,3.45,0.5],[2.22,1.30,3.00,0.7]]

count = 0
for i in l1:
    for j in l2:
        if i == j:
            count+=1
```

Zip function does not work on this case since it will compare i-th element from each of the argument sequences. For example:

```
[i for i, j in zip(l1, l2) if i == j]
```

outputs

```
[([1.0, 1.65, 3.45, 0.5], [1.35, 2.0, 3.6, 0.7]), ([1.8, 1.9, 3.0, 0.5], [1.02, 1.89, 3.45, 0.5]), ([1.02, 1.89, 3.45, 0.5], [2.22, 1.3, 3.0, 0.7])]
```

What Ev. Kounis suggested would work too:

```
count = sum(1 for item in l1 if item in l2)
```

Comment: I have indeed tried this, but my counter still returns 0

Comment: I am getting `count=1` when I used the inefficient code snippet I posted

Comment: or even `sum(1 for item in l1 if item in l2)`

Comment: I get an error like this for the line ´if i==j:´ , ´ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()´ @MassoudHosseinali

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
>>> set(a) & set(b)
{5}
```

or simply

```
>>> set(a).intersection(b)
set([5])
```

Comment: for a complete answer, I would take the length of the created set.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give sample set intersection ?

Here an example use and works for me

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [4,5,6,7]
c = set(a).intersection(b)
similar_count = len(c)
```

I use python 2.7 anyway

**UPDATE**

Declare your variable count outside the loop

Comment: I have tried this, by converting the items as tuples since my list contains multiple arrays and then doing this function but it still does not work @Yuzar Pratama

Comment: Answer of @Massoud Hosseinali its works the problem of your code is you declare variable count inside loop. So value count will be reset to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Can also be done in a single loop.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
for number in a:
    if number in b:
        print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare count=0 outside both loops as after each iteration the value of count is reset to 0 and you get it as answer. modify the code as below:

```
 count=0
 for i in l1:
     for j in l2:
            if i == j:
                count+=1 
            else:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output= [list(item) for item in (set(tuple(row) for row in l1) & set(tuple(row) for row in l2))]
print len(output)
```

Generally, `set` helps to find common elements between two sets easily. For this, we need to convert `list` to a `set`. Since you have a `list of list`, converting it to `set` is not possible without converting it the internal list to a `tuple`.

Output of your example problem:

```
>>> l1 = [[1.00,1.65,3.45,0.5],[1.80,1.90,3.00,0.5],[1.02,1.89,3.45,0.5]]
>>> l2 = [[1.35,2.00,3.60,0.7],[1.02,1.89,3.45,0.5],[2.22,1.30,3.00,0.7]]
>>> output= [list(item) for item in (set(tuple(row) for row in l1) & set(tuple(row) for row in l2))]
>>> print output
[[1.02, 1.89, 3.45, 0.5]]
>>> print len(output)
1
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried this with no luck. Only returns me empty list

Comment: I agree this should work, but it might be a problem higher in the hierarchy, one of the list is compiled from data retrieved from clustering. But this list seems perfectly fine so I am not sure where my bug is